# How to get a activeFocusItem property in qml from main.cpp?

Tags: qt, properties, qml

I'm looking for a way to retrieve qml item properties which are not in type of base types in C++.
I've found this:

```
QWindow *w = (QWindow *)engine.rootObjects().first();
QVariant p = w->property("color");
```

but the result is a instance of QVariant. I want to get properties like `activeFocusItem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in fact you can get the value of `activeFocusItem` if you use the required `toT()` function for the `QVariant`.

In you case it should be something like

```
QQuickWindow *w = (QQuickWindow*) engine.rootObjects().first();
qDebug() << w->activeFocusItem()->property("activeFocus").toBool(); // true obviously
qDebug() << w->activeFocusItem()->property("objectName").toString();
```

In this code, we're getting the properties `activeFocus` and `objectName`, but it's just an example.

Another way,

```
QQuickWindow *w = (QQuickWindow*) engine.rootObjects().first();
QQuickItem *wi = w->property("activeFocusItem").value<QQuickItem*>();
qDebug() << wi->property("activeFocus").toBool();
qDebug() << wi->property("objectName").toString();
```

According to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#details),

> Because C++ forbids unions from including types that have non-default
>   constructors or destructors, most interesting Qt classes cannot be
>   used in unions. Without QVariant, this would be a problem for
>   QObject::property() and for database work, etc.

Usually, you interact with C++ using signals. In that case, when a QML object type is used as a signal parameter, the parameter should use var as the type, and the value should be received in C++ using the `QVariant` type. More info and examples [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#connecting-to-qml-signals).

So `QVariant` is necessary and as I stated before the right way of getting QML objects to be used in C++.

I've [uploaded](https://github.com/ftena/qml-c/tree/master/signal-slot) a complete example to GitHub. I hope this may help you.

Comment: The answer is good, but you should include an example of how to get the `activeFocusItem`, as that is what the question asks for. E.g.: `QQuickItem *activeFocusItem = w->property("activeFocusItem").value<QQuickItem*>();`

Comment: Thank you Tarod and Mitch. actually i can get any property with your code. but for the activeFocusItem i get null ! could you tell me why ?

Comment: @Shnd `activeFocusItem` is null if there is no item with active focus. Maybe this is your case, isn't it? Are you using the class `QQuickWindow`? In your question you're using `QWindow` but I think you should use `QQuickWindow` instead.

Comment: I set `focus:true` on one of my buttons and I checked my code with `QQuickItem`, `QWindow` and `QQuickWindow`. still no chance.

Comment: Post a minimal, complete example, @Shnd. We don't have access to your code.

Comment: @Shnd I suppose the problem is related to how you are getting the `activeFocusItem`. Did you check the code in GitHub?

Comment: Thank you @Tarod for your time and help. I see your code on github and i found couple of interesting things which it will probably help me.
My main issue here is this: I have a qml window with lots of controls. I've used `KeyNavigation.*` to navigate through them with arrow keys. I should find a programatically way to navigate through my controls e.g. write a function called `goToLeftControl()` which when it is called, the focus goes to the left item which has been specified in `KeyNavigation.Left`. (my code should be general and work for every item in qml)

Comment: No problem ;) Yes, I saw your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938621/how-to-send-navigation-key-events-to-qml-in-order-to-change-activefocused-item) and I also saw the @Mitch's comment. Did you read his answer? Is it OK? I think it's better to discuss the issue in that post if this one is actually solved. Or vice versa.

Comment: I'm kinda lost ! in my qml file, on the root element (ApplicationWindow), when i use activeFocusItem, shouldn't it give me the element which currently has a focus? if it's true, why I couldn't access for example a text property of a focused `TextField` by using `activeFocusItem.text`?

Comment: I think this question can solve many of my problems.
why I can't access `activeFocusItem.KeyNavigation.right`

`ApplicationWindow {  
    id: root  
    visible: true  
    title: qsTr("Hello World")  
    onActiveFocusItemChanged: {
        var item = activeFocusItem;
        console.log(activeFocusItem.KeyNavigation.right);
    }

    TextField {
        id: txtupleft
        KeyNavigation.down: txtdownleft
    }

    TextField {
        id: txtdownleft
        KeyNavigation.up: txtupleft
    }
}`

Comment: sry i couldn't find out how to create new lines in comments

Comment: Well, this question is slightly different from the first one you sent some days ago. In any case, I've just updated the code in [GitHub](https://github.com/ftena/qml-c/tree/master/signal-slot) so you can see how to get the text for any `activeFocusItem`. Of course, you should control if the item has or not the text property in order to avoid null objects. Additionally, in the example I've implemented a signal to send the `activeFocusItem` to a C++ class. As I said before, please, post a new question if the issue is different. People should see the answer above, not through the comments.

Comment: The problem was that i checked this in my `main.cpp` file and with `focus:true` in my Qml file, which it seems that it is too soon to ask for focused item in `main.cpp`. I add a new button to my qml and a new class with a public slot and `engine` pointer to the class. then i connect these 2 in my `main.cpp`. in my public slot I've wrote this:
`QObject* root = engine->rootObjects().first();`
    `QQuickItem* item = root->property("activeFocusItem").value<QQuickItem*>();`
    `qDebug() << item->property("text").toString();`
and i get what i expect.

Comment: btw you don't need to cast `engine.rootObjects().first()` return value to `QQuickWindow*`. you can use the default return type `QObject*` too.

Comment: Great, @Shnd! :) Good job!